# Can this code make SQL injection impossible?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-injection

I found this code in DNN PortalSecurity.cs. This is supposed to make input string sql injection safe. I want to know if this code can clean a user input to make it safe to use in a non parametrized query i.e. can it prevent SQL  injection? Do you see any issues here?

```
private string FormatRemoveSQL(string strSQL)
{
    const string BadStatementExpression = ";|--|create|drop|select|insert|delete|update|union|sp_|xp_|exec|/\\*.*\\*/|declare|waitfor|%|&";
    return Regex.Replace(strSQL, BadStatementExpression, " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled).Replace("'", "''");
}
```

Comment: why not parametrized queries?

Comment: Why is `select` a "bad statement"?  Same for `%`?  Seems like it's redacting too much to be a "general" redacter.

Comment: @mybirthname Read the first sentence.  It was yanked from [DotNetNuke/PortalSecurity.cs](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/3358680/)

Comment: Okay my bad I just read between the lines.

Comment: @adt, I am reviewing some code and I found that person using DNN class to sanitize the input. I know parametrized queries would have been a better option.

Comment: It might "work", but it's removing a lot of common English words and punctuation. I don't know why DNN is using this code, but it seems like a very poor replacement for parameterized queries.

Comment: Also, can you clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, I want to know if this code can clean a user input to make it safe to use in a non parametrized query i.e. can It prevent sql injection ?

Comment: Well, it *can*, and *probably* will prevent sql injection, but it's not guaranteed - the source is open, and may be exploitable now or in the future (as keywords are added to SQL Server, for example), **and** it corrupts valid user input. All in all, this is what parameters are for.

Comment: Even if it sanitizes input to prevent SQL Injection it corrupts user input. If the user does not get back the same data they typed in, IMO the system is still broken - perhaps less broken than if SQL injection occurred ... but still broken.

Answer (score 2):

All that is doing is removing common language keywords. For this to be **safe enough**, it would have to be religiously maintained by vendor so from an administrative perspective, it is a nightmare.

Moreover, I highly doubt that list comprises all the potentially dangerous keywords out there. It may also be limiting your ability to enter certain strings (although that might be desired). It may however deter the casual hacker-wanna-be.

I would call this the layman's way of making an input string somewhat safe.

Comment: Indeed, an input filter cannot prevent SQLi in the general case. It is inadequate protection, and it is most probably possible for an attacker to get around it. It is also database specific, an exact attack depends on the DBMS used.